# How can I enable scrolling of the parent document while fancybox is opened?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want a fancybox to appear, but still be able to scroll up and down on the parent page.

Is there a way to do that?

My Fancybox definition:

```
// Fancy box to appear when user scrolls below video
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                autoSize:false,
                modal:false,
                width:400,
                height:'auto',
            });
```

Comment: Fancybox provides that functionality within its API, no need to override any CSS rules. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set as CSS rules to overwrite fancybox's ones:

```
html.fancybox-lock, html.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

html.fancybox-lock body .fancybox-overlay{
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: It hasn't helped. See here: http://info.fibia.dk/LP=259 (scroll at the bottom to see the popup). Thank you

Comment: @OndrejTokar Please try updated answer, including HTML element itself

Comment: It works, I don't understand why setting overflow to visible has helped, but thank you. Feel free to explain it a little if you don't mind. +1

Comment: This is because fancybox uses this [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12090055/1414562) to disable page scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox provides that functionality within its API, no need to override any CSS rules

Just add to your script the `helpers` option like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // API options
    helpers: {
      overlay: {
        locked: false // allows to scroll the parent page
      }
    }
  }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/picssel/tdau3z2p/)**

Comment: Nice and neat answer. Thx